# Which one sounds more correct / natural?

Tags: grammar, adjective

I want to connect two adjectives, one of which is in negative form. As an example:

1. 비싸지 않고 맛있는 식당
2. 안 비싸고 맛있는 식당

It seems to me that 1 is more natural. But can I say 2 instead of 1 without changing the meaning? Does it sound strange?

Comment: Although the second way is usually not used for a lot of compound words, 비싸다 that [*was* a compound word long ago](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/f4073f0c74684dd6b10fff6d3fb59b11) *is* a *simple* word, which means that the second one is also correct.

Comment: @Klmo Thanks for the input. But I really meant to ask a _general_ question about how to connect two adjectives, one of which may be in negative form, rather than a  question that is specific to the word 비싸다 itself

Comment: They are called long/short form negatives. Take a look at [this article](http://isli.khu.ac.kr/journal/content/data/33_3/2.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are asking if the second usage is also *logically* correct. There are *no problems* unless you have chosen an adjective/verb that is unused with 안.

Unlike the English *not*, 안 cannot modify multiple adjectives/verbs at once; it modifies the *nearest* adjective/verb *only*.

An appropriate connector is chosen based on the sentiments *rather than* on the forms. 안 비싸다 and 맛있다 are mostly considered positive, so using -고 is reasonable. This -고 can also be used when both adjectives relate to negative feelings/opinions (e.g. 비싸다 and 맛없다).

When only one of the two adjectives shows a negative opinion (for example, 비싸다 as the negative and 맛있다 as the positive), phrases such as 비싼데 맛있는 것, 비싸도 맛있는 것, 비싸고도 맛있는 것, and 비싸지만 맛있는 것 are used, but you can also use 비싸고 맛있는 것, 비싸면서 맛있는 것, or 비싸고도 맛있는 것 if having a expensive thing makes you feel happy or better.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that 안 only modifies the nearest adjective/verb. I think this is really important.

Answer (score 1):

I think so. I think it is like difference of `do not` and `don't`. First one is more natural to me, too, but second one is ok.

Additionally, There are 2,570,000 google search result for `비싸지 않고 맛있는`, and  4,010,000 for `안 비싸고 맛있는`. I think it is because `안 비싸고 맛있는` is shorter than `비싸지 않고 맛있는`.